# Цикл проверяет только последный ключ обьекта

Tags: javascript

тут при клике на кнопку проверяется то что написано в input-е существует ли в обьекте если да то консолит true в противном случае false. Вопрос, почему проверяет только последный ключ на проверку?

```js
let a4 = {
 3 : 'hello',
 'one' : 'hi',
 'testt' : 'vodoley',
 'ivan' : 'ivanov'
};
let x = document.querySelector(".keys")
let y = document.querySelector(".btn")
for(key in a4){
    y.onclick = ()=>{
        if(x.value == key){
            console.log(true)
        }
        else{
            console.log(false)
        }
            console.log(key,x.value)
    }
}
```

```html
    <input type = "text" class="keys"></input>
    <button class = "btn">Check!</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в размещении цикла, цикл нужно было поместить внутрь обработчика клика, а не обработчик вешать в цикле, поэтому только последний и отрабатывал. Тем более чтобы проверить ключ в объекте, не обязательно прогонять его в цикле есть вариант проще:

```js
let a4 = {
  3: 'hello',
  'one': 'hi',
  'testt': 'vodoley',
  'ivan': 'ivanov'
};
let x = document.querySelector(".keys")
let y = document.querySelector(".btn")
y.onclick = () => {
  console.log(x.value in a4);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="keys"></input>
<button class="btn">Check!</button>
```

Comment: нужно чтобы печатало только 1 true если нашел такой ключ а не true и 2 false

Comment: А так это другой вопрос, отредактировал ответ.